# ggmap plots no map (blank canvas)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Im running R 64bit 3.6.3 on RStudio 1.2.5042 and when I run the code below to produce a plot using ggmap I get a blank canvas. If I export the plot as a PDF the canvas (map tile) is there.

When I try this on a second machine that is running R 64bit 3.5.1 on RStudio 1.1.453 it works fine.

Anyone know what the problem might be?

thanks

mike
[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggmap)
register_google(key = "xxx")
uk <- c(left = -12, bottom = 49, right = 3, top = 61)
map_test<-geocode("London")
ggmap(map) +  
  geom_point(data = map_test, aes(x = lon, y = lat), color = 'red', size = 3)
```